# Read input character by character

Tags: java, input, char

I have a problem with reading input character by character

the sample input is
          3
          first line
          second line
          last line

due to memory constraints i am reading input char by char in for loop and recognizing lines by checking if next char is equal to '\n'.

in this case there is no problem with intermediate lines, but when turn comes to last line the program stops at last char.

what is missing, what is the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: Can you please show your codes which causing problem?

Comment: "due to memory constraints", that's sounds like premature optimization. Why not try using `java.util.Scanner`?

Comment: In that case the last line does not end with `\n`. (You cannot put your cursor on the start of the fourth line.) So check for either end of line or end of file (-1).

Answer (score 1):

Add a symbol at the end of the string to represent end of string and put a check in for loop that if this symbol comes, break from the loop.